# How can I change accents letters to unaccented letters in haskell?

Tags: haskell, replace

Replace the accented letters with their unaccented counterparts!
Example :removeAccents "hétfő" == "hetfo"

```
replaceGivens :: Char -> Char -> String -> String
replaceGivens a _ [] = []
replaceGivens a x (y:ys)
 | a == y  = x : replaceGivens a x ys
 | otherwise = y : replaceGivens a x ys


removeAccents :: String -> String
removeAccents "" = ""
removeAccents b
 | 'á' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'á' 'a' b 
 | 'é' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'é' 'e' b
 | 'í' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'í' 'i' b
 | 'ő' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'ő' 'o' b
 | 'ö' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'ö' 'o' b
 | 'ó' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'ó' 'o' b
 | 'ú' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'ú' 'u' b
 | 'ű' `elem` b   = replaceGivens 'ű' 'u' b
```

Comment: What actually is your question here? — FWIW, I'd say this is a very inefficient approach. Why not just implement the replacement for single characters first, and then map this over the characters in the string? No need to do any `elem` checking first.

Comment: You might want to learn about Haskell [associative arrays](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html) (similar to dictionaries in Python) and their `lookup` function. Like: `accentMap = Data.Map.fromList [('ç','c'), ('à','a'), ... ]`

Comment: Not all accented characters are single characters.